# Is there a OneDrive REST API call to get file revisions metadata - by who and when?

Tags: onedrive

I know that OneDrive does not support file versions, but I have read that Sharepoint does support file versions.

But Sharepoint is not OneDrive. I was unable to find API calls to see who made changes to files, but I can see in the OneDrive web front end there is a way to see the revision data (different times the file was modified and by who).  Is there an API call to retrieve this data (by who and when the file was modified and not the different versions of the file)? I was unable to find an api call in the documentation.

Note: I am not looking to get different versions of the file, just the modification history of the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the versions api. You can call this api as follows:

https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/root:/test.docx:/versions

This will return the metadata associated with the file versions. It does have lastModifiedDateTime, but is missing lastModifiedBy property. If I find some documentation for the api, I will update my answer with it. In the meantime, feel free to reach me in case you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It looks like <file>:/versions is a SharePoint api and not a OneDrive api. /versions is not listed at [this url](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm)